# seeing who liked a page programmatically

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

So my company has a facebook page and they're wanting to pay the sales people bonuses based on how many of each of their customers liked my companies facebook page.

To do that right now someone in our marketing department is manually going through, getting the names, and doing queries one-by-one, to see if the person who liked the page is a customer and if so who's customer they are.

That seems excessively tedious. My question is... is there a way to automate that? I don't see anything in the Graph API / Page stuff that'd let you do that:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

For that matter I'm not actually entirely sure how our marketing person is getting the names of people who liked the page. When I view the page I just see who, among my friends, liked the page. But then again they are an admin whereas I'm currently not (although I could get it fairly easily if I can show how my having admin access would be of benefit [and this would qualify I'm sure]).

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Querying Users who 'like' my Facebook Page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5183251/querying-users-who-like-my-facebook-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no. You can't see who liked your page programmatically, you can only see manually on your facebook page if you go to the new likes section.

You can create a page app that when a user likes your page it prompts him to insert his information or something like that, but then again you won't capture the likes that are made directly on your page, only the ones made inside de app

Comment: Just to clarify: you can certainly capture a user's likes and interests and check for your page, it'd just require an install.